# Unable to read an excel file in python

Tags: python, excel

So I have a path here which contains many excel files

```
path = ""
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
```

I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'censo2001 (1).xls'

For reference, the first file in the folder is named 'censo2001 (1)' and it has an .xls extension. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use the full path: `open_workbook(path + file)`

Comment: Worked! Thank you! What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Your current location is not the file location.